# Adding scale bar in ArcMap data view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, scale-bar

How to add a dynamic scale bar in (or close to) map extent while **data view** is turned on?

I'm panning a lot (raster images) and I need to get more precise "feel" of distances just in one glance since I'm panning in various scales.

Comment: I know, that it is possible to tell (exact) scale after lot's of practicing hours, but I need to optimize something right now.

Comment: You can always refer to the "scale" near the zoom buttons, add a scale in layout view while exploring your data frame, or use the measure tool.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: I'd use multiple fishnets

Comment: Could you just pan and zoom within the layout view using the pan and zoom tool within the "Tools" toolbar (data view toolbar)?

Answer (score 2):

You can add scale bars to the Layout view, but not to the Data view.  This may be possible with an Add-In but I am not aware of any available, although a thorough google search may turn one up.

There is an existing idea on the Esri Ideas page asking for them to be added to ArcGIS - 
[Dynamic scale bar for data view](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/5969)

Comment: ESRI Ideas takes ages to get anywhere, OP mine as well look for a 3rd party plugin if you really need one.

Comment: @Joe Esri Ideas take votes to get anywhere.  If there is no third-party add-in available and if they have no ability to write one themselves, then voting on the idea will be the only option.  It is not possible in ArcMap currently.

Comment: I agree I was just implying to OP don't expect ESRI to release this anytime soon (for your project needs)

Comment: Still thank's for the info. I already voted for availability!